# how to serialize/deserialize arrayList(Object)

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization

I have an `ArrayList<ItemList>`

where ItemList is:

```
public class ItemList {
    public ArrayList<Item> it = new ArrayList<Item>();
    public String name = "";

    public ItemList() {
    }
}
```

and Item is:

```
public class Item {
    public String name = "";
    public int count = 0;

    public Item() {
    }
}
```

I try to serialize this list:

```
try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(sdDir + serFile);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(List_Of_Lists);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I think it's work, becouse I find this file in folder.

But I can't deserialize from file to `ArrayList<ItemList>`

code:

```
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(sdDir + serFile);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            List_Of_Lists = (ArrayList<ItemList>) in.readObject(); 
            Log.i("palval", "dir.exists()");
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How I can deserialize this `ArrayList<ItemList>`?
I always catch IOException.

Comment: Please post the entire exception stacktrace

Comment: Are you serializing the arraylist only i.e. the "it" variable or the class ItemList ?

Comment: 'I always catch IOException'. Yes but did you read the message it contains? It contains the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `Item` and `ItemList` classes needs to `implements Serializable`

Comment: What is item implement parcelable? Can it implement serializable at the same time?

Comment: @the_prole I am not sure what you mean by "What is item implement parcelable?". About "Can it implement serializable at the same time" probably yes since class can implement many interfaces and `Serializable` doesn't really introduce any new methods so there shouldn't be any conflict.

Comment: Sorry. I mean, **what if item already implements parcelable**?

Comment: I can't say for sure since I am not Android developer. But if I would need to guess I would say that since `Serializable` doesn't introduce any methods (it is marker interface) you should be fine (simply use mechanism you want, one defined in Parcelable or one using Serializable).

Comment: @the_prole But this is only opinion of someone who never developed in Android so I may be wrong. Anyway my answer is based on assumption that `ObjectOutputStream` in Android is using mechanism involving Serializable (I didn't get any complains till now so I am assuming that I was right) which is why I pointed that interface (I also wasn't aware of existence of `Parcelable` till now).

Answer (score 0):

if you have made subclass then add serializabe method to parent class it will remove the error.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you have serialized the ItemList not the Item.....

```
ArrayList<ItemList> arr = (ArrayList<ItemList>) in.readObject();

for (ItemList a : arr) 
   {
        // In this loop by iterating arr, you will get the whole List of ItemList

   }
```

Comment: ok..try and let me know..actually dont have your complete code, so its hard to guess

Comment: Item, ItemList needs to implements Serializable.